# Multi Threading from a function to another function and back to the main function

Tags: python, arduino, serial-port, arduino-uno

currently this is my setup, python in PyCharm, and an Arduino Uno with MAX30100 sensor for heart rate. I am currently able to transmit data via pyserial into my pycharm from arduino, and will show the heartrate in pycharm.
But I want my program to run the webcam feed ***WHILE*** showing the sensor reading at the same time.
Currently my ***SIMPLIFIED*** code is as below :

```
class start_workout_session():

def pushup(self):
   
    #cam start here ~~!!
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    with mp_pose.Pose(min_detection_confidence=1.5, min_tracking_confidence=1.5) as pose:

        while cap.isOpened():
           
            # Extract landmarks
            try:
             
               calculate angle here

               Showing angle in frame by using putText method from cv2
               
               Curl counter logic

               Render curl counter

                t1 = threading.Thread(target=arduino)
                t1.start()
    
               cv2.imshow('i-Trainer', image)

        cap.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()



def arduino():
serialInst = serial.Serial()
serialInst.baudrate = 9600
serialInst.port = 'COM3'
serialInst.open()
while True:
    if serialInst.inWaiting:
        packet = serialInst.readline()
        print(packet.decode('utf').rstrip('\n'))

time.sleep(1)

t2 = threading.Thread(target=pushup)
t2.start()
t1.join()
t2.join()
```

this program can run but it always prompts an error :

```
File "C:\Users\..\main.py", line 629, in arduino
    serialInst.open()



File "C:\Users\..\Python36\lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 64, in open
    raise SerialException("could not open port {!r}: {!r}".format(self.portstr, ctypes.WinError()))
serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port 'COM3': PermissionError(13, 'Access is denied.', None, 5)
```

Comment: It looks like the issue is that you're creating a new Arduino thread inside the camera loop. So the second time round you'll try and open the serial port again and get the error since it's already open. Normally when reading from the serial port you just start a thread at the beginning - similar to how you're starting the camera thread - and let it run in the background. You can set a flag to exit the loop at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @cguk70,

i managed to solve the problem, by putting the

```
 t1 = threading.Thread(target=arduino)
                t1.start()
```

outside together with

```
#cam start here ~~!!
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
```

reason is that i am creating a new Arduino thread inside the camera loop. So the second time round you'll try and open the serial port again and get the error since it's already open.